# How to get metadata from Talend Data Management Platform?

Tags: talend, openai-api, talend-mdm, data-lineage

I'm building a Data Lineage and for that I need the metadata about the Talend jobs, schemas and tables associated with each job.

I went through the documentation but there was only one way to get that data and that was using GUI.
I want to automate the metadata gathering and thereby cleaning it appropriately using code.

Using ChatGPT I found out that there is **Talend Metadata API** which can be used to get the metadata but there was nothing mentioned of it in the Documentation.

Comment: Maybe?  https://api.eu.cloud.talend.com/tmc/swagger/swagger-ui.html#

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't contain any APIs for metadata of databases and tables.

Comment: Why should Talend give you metadata on DB tables and the like?  Go to the DB for that.  I think you mean schema information for components within a job, no?

Comment: Yeah I need that.